# QT: Error [expected ")" before "*" token and MainWindow does not name a type]

Tags: c++, qt

I got two errors in Qt, I wish you can help me with this. This is my first time I post something, please me help. This is the code:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <QtCore>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

class HiloPrincipal : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

   explicit HiloPrincipal( MainWindow* parent = 0); // First error


   MainWindow * _parent; // Second error

   void run(); // Sacar Botella y poner botella.


signals:

public slots:

};
#endif // HILOS_H
```

Comment: You could show more information of your code besides showing the complete error.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Publish the relevant content of `mainwindow.h`. It seems that there is a missing declaration (probably a name typo or you forgot to include a header file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost sure you have created include cycle.
Fix it like this:

```
#ifndef HILOS_H // this was missing! Probably when you did copy paste to question
#define HILOS_H

#include <QMainWindow>
// remove line: #include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <QtCore>
// remove line: #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

// forward declaration
class MainWindow;

class HiloPrincipal : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

   explicit HiloPrincipal( MainWindow* parent = 0); // First error


   MainWindow * _parent; // Second error

   void run(); // Sacar Botella y poner botella.


signals:

public slots:

};
#endif // HILOS_H
```

Than include this headers files `mainwindow.h` in `HiloPrincipal.cpp`. This should solve build issue, but not actual problem.

Note problem is caused by invalid design of classes. Your `HiloPrincipal` thread shouldn't have any knowledge about `MainWindow`.

Also [you're doing that wrong](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) - this is invalid use of `QThread`.

Comment: Note that [You were not doing so wrong.](https://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html). Subclassing QThread is valid, if you're not using its event mechanism for communicating with QObjects

Comment: yes it is valid, but creates more complex problems, so it is recommended not to do this. There are many advantages when using composition instead of subclassing, but this is a big off topic in case of this question.

Comment: Indeed, it is too broad. But generally discouraging to subclass QThread is wrong - and I just wanted to point that out.